# Access Crosstab subtotal columns

Tags: ms-access, crosstab

I have a following question regarding crosstabs in Access:
How do I create a subtotal columns?

What I want to see as a result of the query is this:

```
          Nov 2010     Dec 2010     2010 Total     Jan 2011    Feb 2011 
Row1             2            4             17            3           2
Row2             8            6             35            7           5
```

How do I create these subtotals for the year? (It's ok, if the year data will be in the end, after all months)
The problem is that I need to do this without hardcoding each year, the query should work with any dataset

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In Access I think it's much easier to perform totalizing in reports. Design your queries to get the data you need, add your totals in the PRESENTATION of that data...ie, reports

Answer (score 2):

Say we have raw [SalesData]

```
SalesYear   SalesMonth  Region  SalesTotal
---------   ----------  ------  ----------
2010        11          East    45
2010        11          West    58
2010        12          East    55
2010        12          West    63
2011        1           East    51
2011        1           West    54
2011        2           East    55
2011        2           West    61
```

We can create a [SalesTotals] query to combine the monthly sales totals with the yearly totals...

```
SELECT SalesYear & "-" & Format(SalesMonth, "00") AS SalesPeriod, Region, SalesTotal FROM SalesData
UNION ALL
SELECT SalesYear & "-Total", Region, SUM(SalesTotal) FROM SalesData GROUP BY SalesYear, Region;
```

...which produces

```
SalesPeriod Region  SalesTotal
----------- ------  ----------
2010-11     East    45
2010-11     West    58
2010-12     East    55
2010-12     West    63
2011-01     East    51
2011-01     West    54
2011-02     East    55
2011-02     West    61
2010-Total  East    100
2010-Total  West    121
2011-Total  East    106
2011-Total  West    115
```

Then we can do our crosstab query on the [SalesTotals] query...

```
TRANSFORM Sum(SalesTotals.[SalesTotal]) AS SumOfSalesTotal
SELECT SalesTotals.[Region]
FROM SalesTotals
GROUP BY SalesTotals.[Region]
PIVOT SalesTotals.[SalesPeriod];
```

...which produces

```
Region  2010-11 2010-12 2010-Total  2011-01  2011-02  2011-Total
------  ------- ------- ----------  -------  -------  ----------
East    45      55      100         51       55       106
West    58      63      121         54       61       115
```