# SQL Statement for MS Access Query to Calculate Quarterly Growth Rate

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, oledb

I have a table named "Historical_Stock_Prices" in a MS Access database.  This table has the columns: Ticker, Date1, Open1, High, Low, Close1, Volume, Adj_Close.  The rows consist of the data for each ticker for every business day.

I need to run a query from inside my VB.net program that will return a table in my program that displays the growth rates for each quarter of every year for each ticker symbol listed. So for this example I would need to find the growth rate for GOOG in the 4th quarter of 2012.

To calculate this manually I would need to take the Close Price on the last BUSINESS day of the 4th quarter (12/31/2012) divided by the Open Price of the first BUSINESS day of the 4th quarter (10/1/2012). Then I need to subtract by 1 and multiply by 100 in order to get a percentage.

The actual calculation would look like this: ((707.38/759.05)-1)*100 = -6.807%

The first and last days of each quarter may vary due to weekend days.

I cannot come up with the correct syntax for the SQL statement to create a table of Growth Rates from a table of raw Historical Prices.  Can anyone help me with the SQL statment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would approach the problem:

I'd start by creating a saved query Access named [Stock_Price_with_qtr] that calculates the year and quarter for each row:

```
SELECT 
    Historical_Stock_Prices.*, 
    Year([Date1]) AS Yr, 
    Switch(Month([Date1])<4,1,Month([Date1])<7,2,Month([Date1])<10,3,True,4) AS Qtr
FROM Historical_Stock_Prices
```

Then I'd create another saved query in Access named [Qtr_Dates] that finds the first and last business days for each ticker and quarter:

```
SELECT 
    Stock_Price_with_qtr.Ticker, 
    Stock_Price_with_qtr.Yr, 
    Stock_Price_with_qtr.Qtr, 
    Min(Stock_Price_with_qtr.Date1) AS Qtr_Start, 
    Max(Stock_Price_with_qtr.Date1) AS Qtr_End
FROM Stock_Price_with_qtr
GROUP BY 
    Stock_Price_with_qtr.Ticker, 
    Stock_Price_with_qtr.Yr, 
    Stock_Price_with_qtr.Qtr
```

That would allow me to use the following query in VB.NET (or C#, or Access itself) to calculate the quarterly growth rates:

```
SELECT 
    Qtr_Dates.Ticker, 
    Qtr_Dates.Yr, 
    Qtr_Dates.Qtr, 
    (([Close_Prices]![Close1]/[Open_Prices]![Open1])-1)*100 AS Qtr_Growth
FROM 
    (
        Historical_Stock_Prices AS Open_Prices 
        INNER JOIN Qtr_Dates 
        ON (Open_Prices.Ticker = Qtr_Dates.Ticker) 
            AND (Open_Prices.Date1 = Qtr_Dates.Qtr_Start)
    ) 
    INNER JOIN 
    Historical_Stock_Prices AS Close_Prices 
    ON (Qtr_Dates.Ticker = Close_Prices.Ticker)
        AND (Qtr_Dates.Qtr_End = Close_Prices.Date1)
```

Comment: Alright!!  I tried to put all three queries into Access.  The first two were entered no problem.  The last query gives an error that says "Syntax error in SQL expression".

Comment: @nordeen1 Check your last query for typos. I just copied and pasted the last query from my answer into both Access 2010 and C# 2010 Express and in each case the query worked fine.

Comment: It won't work in Access or VB.net.  I also copy and pasted the queries from your answer into Access and got the error.  I also checked for typos and didn't find any.  Now I tried putting the last query into my program and it give me the error "The Microsoft Jet database engine cannot find the input table or query `Qtr_Dates`.  Make sure it exists and that its name is spelled correctly".  I've checked and my queries are labeled `Qtr_Dates` and `Stock_Price_with_qtr`.

Comment: Here is the SQL statment I used in my code `Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT Qtr_Dates.Ticker, Qtr_Dates.Yr, Qtr_Dates.Qtr, (([Close_Prices]![Close1]/[Open_Prices]![Open1])-1)*100 AS Qtr_Growth FROM (Historical_Stock_Prices AS Open_Prices INNER JOIN Qtr_Dates ON (Open_Prices.Ticker = Qtr_Dates.Ticker) AND (Open_Prices.Date1 = Qtr_Dates.Qtr_Start)) INNER JOIN Historical_Stock_Prices AS Close_Prices ON (Qtr_Dates.Ticker = Close_Prices.Ticker) AND (Qtr_Dates.Qtr_End = Close_Prices.Date1)", Nordeen_Investing_3.con)`

Comment: @nordeen1 Did you enter the first two queries into Access and *save* them in Access (using the exact names that are referenced in the last query)?

Comment: Yes they are saved and I believe the names are referenced correctly.  I am actually using OpenOffice on this computer so that may be a problem.  I'll have to switch computers to use Access but I have not had a problem using OpenOffice in place of Access to this point with my program.  Is it possible to create and save the first two queries from within my program? Thanks!

Comment: @nordeen1 re: "Is it possible to create and save the first two queries from within my program?" - Yes, you can use DDL to create the saved queries in the Access database from your VB.NET application. Just use an `OleDbCommand` object to execute `CREATE VIEW Stock_Price_with_qtr AS SELECT Historical_Stock_Prices.*, ...`.

Comment: I switched to Access instead of OpenOffice and everything worked great!  I've marked your original response as the correct answer. Now I'll work to create the queries from within my program to account for my lack of access to Microsoft Access.  I have one minor question about the formatting of the final query though.  Right now the final query displays columns of Ticker, Year, Qtr, Qtr_Growth.  And a row for every quarter for every year of every ticker.  I would like to display this table in my program as columns 2013-1, 2012-4, 2012-3 and only one row for every ticker. Thanks!

Comment: @nordeen1 You could create a crosstab (PIVOT) query to take the results from the last query and reformat them as you've described. The approach would be similar to my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16202008/access-crosstab-subtotal-columns/16210688#16210688). If you need help with that please open a new question.

Comment: The first two queries work fine within my program. I get an error when I copy and paste this SQL statement for the last query `SELECT Qtr_Dates.Ticker, Qtr_Dates.Yr, Qtr_Dates.Qtr, (([Close_Prices]![Close1]/[Open_Prices]![Open1])-1)*100 AS Qtr_Growth FROM (Historical_Stock_Prices AS Open_Prices INNER JOIN Qtr_Dates ON (Open_Prices.Ticker = Qtr_Dates.Ticker) AND (Open_Prices.Date1 = Qtr_Dates.Qtr_Start)) INNER JOIN Historical_Stock_Prices AS Close_Prices ON (Qtr_Dates.Ticker = Close_Prices.Ticker) AND (Qtr_Dates.Qtr_End = Close_Prices.Date1)", Nordeen_Investing_3.con)`

Comment: This is the error `Additional information: Cannot join on Memo, OLE, or Hyperlink Object (Open_Prices.Ticker=Qtr_Dates.Ticker And Open_Prices.Date1=Qtr_Dates.Qtr_Start).`

Comment: If [Ticker] is a `Memo` field you will have to change it to `Text`.

Comment: [Ticker] is created with this line of code.  I don't believe it is a `Memo` field. `Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("CREATE TABLE " & tblName & "(Ticker Text NOT NULL, Date1 Date NOT NULL, Open1 Money, High Money, Low Money, Close1 Money, Volume Long, Adj_Close Money, CONSTRAINT pk_TickerDate PRIMARY KEY (Ticker, Date1));", Nordeen_Investing_3.con)`

Comment: `Ticker Text NOT NULL,` may very well create a `Memo` field because it does not specify a maximum length. `Ticker Text(10) NOT NULL,` (or similar) might work better.